# Stop an Android app that Eclipse says is running (even though it isn't)?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I did the first lesson in the Android tutorial and ran it in the emulator. Now, the tooltip on the Run button says that it's still running, even though I had shut the emulator down. Now I want to run the app on my phone, but I can't because when I click the Run button, it automatically opens the emulator. How do I force the app to stop so that Eclipse knows it's not running anymore and allows me to choose my phone as the device to run it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to stop a app: You need to open the **debug perspective** or short **DDMS** in ecllipse. It is beside java. If its not visible then open it from window. In the ddms perspective you have a toolbar called devices showing currently active device or emulator. Select the device and search the running process in this case your app's packagename and stop it from the same toolbar.

Also to solve the run on emulaor (by default) you need to provide a run configuration. It goes something like this:
Run->Run Configurations -> Android Application -> 3 tabs visible -> tab Android under project select your project -> tab Target select launch on all compatible devices and then select active devices -> 3rd tab select both debug and run and hit run.

Comment: In my case, the app's package name was not appearing in the list of running processes. However, the second paragraph solved my problem as to which device it runs on by default. (I set it to always prompt me so that I can choose between my phone and the emulator.)